# Trying to authenticate via the API results in "Oops! something bad happened"

Tags: bug, api, oauth

Since 10/16/2015, Stack Exchange OAuth has been failing for us with an unexpected error from Stack Exchange in Authorize flow.
- User gets navigated to Stack Exchange login page.
- User chooses to login with "Stack Exchange" account.
- User enters credentials and presses sign-in.
- User gets redirected to generic error page with title "Oops! something bad happened" with description that something unexpected occurred on Stack Exchange side.

Same app and code was working before 10/16. I've also tried with multiple users and by registering new apps but no luck so far. Is there some known issue going on? Can someone please try on their side to get additional repros. What other details should I capture to further investigate this issue.

Comment: You're talking about the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication), right? Not OpenID used to login into the sites? Anyway since users are still using the official apps, which use the same API, it's probably not some global issue with the API.

Comment: [Blaze](http://erwaysoftware.com/blaze) (client-side flow) is working fine for me.

Comment: yes, its happening in API flow. Noticed that issue is only happening if user has to signin to StackExchange in OAuth flow.